# Parsing file using finite state machine

Tags: java, finite-automata, fsm, state-machine

I am implementing my own fsm to parse a file. I am new to fsm pattern so trying to learn about it.

My fsm class takes a stream of the file that is being parsed along with the current state and a collection of all accepting states.

Now I am confused about couple of things.

1. How does the fsm move through states and keep track of what has been parsed so far?
2. What information should the state object store? Right now they have a pattern that they match on the line and see if fsm can move to this state or not.

Example:

File to parse:

```
Person:  bob smith
        Age: 33
        Location: new York
End person
Person:  Jane smith
        Age: 66
        Location: Chicago
End person
```

So I have a state for person start, age, location and end person. Each state object has a patter. (regex) to check if the given line is accepted by them or not.

But I am stuck on how would I construct a Person object when parsing this file using fsm??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a list of persons (empty initially). Have a `currentPerson` variable.

- When the state is "person start", initialize the `currentPerson` variable to a new Person.
- When the state is "age", set the age into the `currentPerson`.
- Same for the "location" state.
- When the state is "end of person", add the currentPerson to the list of persons.

When you reach the end of the file, the list of persons contains all your persons.

Comment: This will parse Person objects, but nothing more.  Assuming that's all the asker wants, it will work, but is a very limited grammar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I agree that this is the best use of FSM.

This looks an awful lot like JSON to me.  A few changes and you're there.  It could easily be XML too; you wouldn't have to write a parser.

But, if you insist, your FSM will start at reading a line.

If the line contains "Person", you'll save the name value.  (Recommendation: add a "Name" line after "Person".)

If the line contains "Age", you'll save the age value.

If the line contains "Location", you'll save the location value.

If the line contains "End", you'll instantiate a new Person, add it to a data structure, and read the next line.

If the line is null you've reached the end; transition to the end state and close the file.

You don't say whether or not you allow any of the attributes out of order.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of building state in an FSM is to construct a tree as you read in tokens.  The state of the FSM is determined by what kind of node you're currently under.  For example, you'd start by parsing the word 'Person' and so you'd know to build a new 'Person' node in the tree.  Then, everything you read past that, until you reach the 'End Person' tokens, creates nodes under that 'Person'.

As an academic exercise, this sounds good for an FSM.  But for practical purposes, this does look like JSON, so I would definitely look for existing ways of parsing it.

Also, yacc (or bison) is the definitive way of building FSM parsers.  It spits out C code given a formally defined grammar.  I've never looked into it, but there is probably something similar out there for Java.